# How to create a dependent Guice (Play / Scala) binding?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, akka, guice

I am using Scala + Play and the out of box Guice set up for dependency injection.  I am also using Akka Persistence behind the scenes and would like to create a binding for a custom read journal that I can then inject around my application.

Unfortunately, the read journal constructor (which I do not control) requires an explicit reference to the actor system:

```
PersistenceQuery(actorSystem).readJournalFor[CustomReadJournal]("custom-key")
```

How do I get a reference to the underlying `actorSystem` from within a binding definition class (`Module`)?  Is this possible?  More generally, is it possible to define interdependent bindings (a la Scaldi?)

My `Module` class entry currently looks like:

```
bind(classOf[CustomReadJournal]).toInstance(PersistenceQuery(<what do i put here?>).readJournalFor[CustomReadJournal]("custom-journal"))
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you looked into using @Provides and providing your actorSystem as a parameter so that you can inject that as well? If you need to provide another one, you can use the akka system built into play through play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system(Play.current)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do some kind of logic to create a dependency injection it is useful to use the [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) annotation. For example:

```
trait MyProvider {
  @Provides
  def provideThing(): Thing = {
    //make the thing and return it
  }
}
class MyModule extends AbstractModule with MyProvider {
   override def configure() {
     bind(classOf[TraitYYY]).to(classOf[ClassThatTakesThingAsParameter])
   }
}
```

A useful thing to know is that `@Provides` methods can themselves take parameters and get their arguments injected. For example:

```
@Provides
def provideThingNeedingParameter(param: P): ThingNeedingParam = {
   new ThingNeedingParam(param)
}
```

Which is relevant to your situation I believe since you want to *provide* an actor system to an instance of some class.

```
// You can use @Singleton with @Provides if you need this to be one as well!
@Provides
def provideActorSystem(app: Application): ActorSystem = {
    play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system(app)
}

@Provides
def providePersistenceQuery(actorSystem: ActorSystem): PersistenceQuery = {
    PersistenceQuery(actorSystem)
}

@Provides 
def provideCustomReadJournal(persistenceQuery: PersistenceQuery):CustomReadJournal = {
    persistenceQuery.readJournalFor[CustomReadJournal]("custom-key")    
}
```

By creating an `@Provides` annotated method for your CustomReadJournal you can avoid the `bind` call from configure entirely and control the parameters a bit more. Also, if you need to, @Provides works with @Singleton. I haven't used Akka persistence, but I think this should help you